# Comfortable place for rabbits in the snow

Tags: rabbits, containment, weather

I have two rabbits in my garden. This will be their first winter in this garden, the rabbits had two winters in our last garden.
The last garden had a lot of bushes and plants to hide in and find a nice place for the rabbits. But the new one only has 3 tall bushes (tall with no green on bottom side, so no hiding) and grass.

The rabbits have a hut to protect them from cold and the weather. But they do use it only for very cold times (like a burrow). I assume they like and need to look around to feel save.

Because of that I am searching for a thing I could buy or build that would give them a comfortable place to sit. I imagine a place without snow, maybe without wind, but with clear sight around. I need an artificial bush

Does anyone have experience with human-build furniture for rabbits, which fulfills my constrains? 
Are there other characteristics I should have in mind?

Comment: How do you keep them supplied with water that is not frozen?

Comment: I change every morning and evening the water bowl. Most time (all year long) they do not use the bowl much. If there is snow they eat some. But most water they get with fresh food.

Comment: @JamesJenkins I have asked an own question for this :) [non freezing drinking water](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/26709/how-to-avoid-water-to-drink-freezes-outside)

Answer (score 1):

Now, as the winter is over (the second one, since I asked my question), I found some kind of solution:

I built a "tipi" from conifer twigs (For all foreign people - like me: conifer are the group of trees with needles instead of leaves, not like in for example German , where "Konifere" is one particular species)

You should choose a native European species, to ensure your rabbits can try a bit and stay safe. But if they are well fed with various kind of foods, you do not need to worry about them eating the conifer twigs. They would only try, if they are starving.

Sadly, I missed taking a picture of the building itself, but I will include a sketch and an additional picture of the "porch" I built onto their regular hutch.

[image: scratch of a conifere-tipi]

[image: two rabbits in the snow]